# Phonegap-Android : Using Arabic/Persian fonts

Tags: android, cordova, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Question is : How can I use Arabic(or Persian) fonts in Phonegap ?

I tried converting them to all formats then using them with @font-face

But it just shows me rectangles (But works in PC)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No one knows the answer ?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@font-face` in css file.

At first, create font folder under assets then copy your font in this folder and use @font-face for applying your font but font doesn't apply for text in android 4.x .

I hope it can help you.

Comment: does @font-face work on android 4.0 ?
can you change arabic and farsi fonts in android ?

Comment: I'v found another way with java! google it! changing app font and then using it in webview